# What's wrong with the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

My problem is that I can't create a table of contents for my document. I just use

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
...
  \newpage      
    \tableofcontents
```

but it's generating nothing but the word "Contents"! 
However TeXstudio, in the left sidebar, is showing all sections and stuff.

[image]

When I open the `.toc` file with `notepad++` there's only this string

```
\select@language {russian}
```

Example

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}


\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\lstset{
  language=php,
  numbers=none,
  tabsize=3,
  breaklines=true,
  aboveskip=1ex,
  belowskip=1ex,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  framerule=0pt,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false
}

\begin{document}
    \newpage
        \tableofcontents
\newpage
        \begin{center}
            \section*{Краткая характеристика}
        \end{center}
        В данной работе рассматривается создание и управление базой данных для веб-сайта. На примерах рассмотрена регистрация пользователей на сайте, осуществление восстановления логина/пароля пользователя, так же рассмотрены функции администратора сайта - добавление/удаление информации и объектов.

        Все формы созданы на языке гипертекстовой разметки HTML, для создания сценариев взаимодействия с базами данных используется язык PHP.

        Применяемая СУБД: MySQL.

        Для администрирования СУБД использовалось приложение PHPMyAdmin.

\end{document}
```

Comment: And (just to be sure) do you run the document twice?

Comment: For this kind of problem, you should clear out all auxiliary files and start clean. Delete `.toc` and `.aux` files and recompile (at least twice).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yep, even more than twice

Comment: @Werner well, its not helped me

Comment: What document class are you using? Do you get any warning/error messages (if so, please add them verbatim to your question)? Can we please see a small but complete skeleton of your document?

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you receive any errors or warnings during compilation? Think of the problem from the community's (our) perspective. We need to be able to reproduce the problem in order to adequately assess where things might go wrong. For that, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) is usually best. If that cannot be produced we need a bucket-load more information...

Comment: @Werner well, only few errors like that `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:â\lst@EC\lst@EC not set up for use`. I think it's because of i type in russian language

Comment: @DanilGholtsman: Well, "only a few" is enough to result in such problems. You need a UTF-capable editor at least, otherwise input (when using [`inputenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc)) isn't interpreted correctly.

Comment: @Stephen I edited my question. It was saying that `Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_PH1800".tex

Process exited normally`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `\section*{...}`. This will format its text like a section, but the section will not be numbered and it will not be listed in the table of contents. Remove the star, compile twice, and the section should appear in the toc. If you want to have different entries in the toc and in the main text (for example if the section title is much too long for the toc), you can use `\section[toc title]{section title}`, where "toc title" goes into the toc and "section title" is written in the main text.

As more MWE you could look at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section[Some section title]{\centering Some longer section title}

\section*{\centering Another section title}
\end{document}
```

and the result when compiling it (twice).

I should also mention `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section title only in toc}` which adds an entry(-line including page number) to the toc (`lof` would add to the list of figures, `lot` to tables,...), formatted as `section`, but would not write anything in the main text.

Comment: @DanilGholtsman You're welcome! Sometimes such small things have big effects and are hard to find (I know that from experience...).